# How to add values to SQL database on windows form

Tags: c#

I have been using visual studio c# windows form for a project. I have a signup with text boxes that take in inputs for username and password. The message boxes are called txtUser and txtPass. What would I need to code to ensure the username and password are added into the SQL database and for it to create a unique UserID for the primary key.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need the use SqlData Client namespace

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
```

Theny you need to create a connection with your connection string and then open the connection

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(YourConnectionString);
connection.Open();
```

Then create SQL Command with your query string and Sql Connection. You need to create your INSERT query with the textbox values.

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(QueryString, connection);
```

Finally since you are inserting just execute your query and then close your connection.

```
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
connection.Close();
```